# In Swift Spritekit, whenever I transition from one Scene to another, my sks file is not transfering?

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

Basically I have a `MenuScene` and a `GameScene` for my game. The `MenuScene` is first as shown in the `viewDidLoad` function from `ViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = MenuScene(fileNamed:"MenuScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

}
```

There is a simple menu screen with a play button that transfers right into the game. Here is the if-block in my `touchesBegan` method:

```
if node == playButton {
            playButton.size.height=playButton.size.height+30
            playButton.size.width=playButton.size.height+30
            if view != nil {


                let transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
                let scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
            }
        }
```

But when it transitions into my `GameScene`, the sks files for my `GameScene` doesn't render? And all the variables in my `GameScene.swift` that connects to the sprites in the `sks` file are missing. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `if let newScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {...}`

Comment: if change GameScene(size: self.size) to GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") what happens?

Comment: As everyone has already pointed out, `GameScene(size: self.size)` does not load SKS files, it only loads the class behind the SKS file.  the `fileNamed` initializer is the only one that loads up a seperate file.  As a side note, you can use the `customClass` field in the sks to define the class that needs to be loaded, and do `let scene = SKScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`

`let scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)` means that you are loading an instance of type `GameScene`.  At no point will it load any file.

`SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")` on the other hand will load a file, just be sure to check that the custom class field on your sks file says `GameScene`

Comment: Hope you do not mind, I corrected and cleaned up your answer so that you can get some upvotes